# What is the canonical audio sample data type in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, core-audio

In the iOS 5.0 documentation it is stated that the canonical audio data type is 16 bit signed int ([link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/MusicAudio/Reference/CoreAudioDataTypesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004488-CH3-SW6)):

> The canonical audio data sample type for input and output.
>
> typedef SInt16 AudioSampleType;
>
> Discussion
>
> The canonical audio sample type for input and output in iPhone OS is
>   linear PCM with 16-bit integer samples.

However if I right-click "jump to definition" on `AudioSampleType` I see the following definition, in `CoreAudioTypes.h`:

```
#if !CA_PREFER_FIXED_POINT
typedef Float32     AudioSampleType;
typedef Float32     AudioUnitSampleType;
#else
typedef SInt16      AudioSampleType;
typedef SInt32      AudioUnitSampleType;
#define kAudioUnitSampleFractionBits 24
#endif
```

and again when jump-to-def for `CA_PREFER_FIXED_POINT` I see:

```
#if !defined(CA_PREFER_FIXED_POINT)
    #if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
        #if (TARGET_CPU_X86 || TARGET_CPU_X86_64 || TARGET_CPU_PPC || TARGET_CPU_PPC64) && !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
            #define CA_PREFER_FIXED_POINT 0
        #else
            #define CA_PREFER_FIXED_POINT 1
        #endif
    #else
        #define CA_PREFER_FIXED_POINT 0
    #endif
#endif
```

Checking in my code at run-time, I see that `CA_PREFER_FIXED_POINT` is defined to be 1, both on the simulator and on my iPod.

So, my questions:

- What **is** the canonical type? Is it *always* `SInt16` on the device?
- Under what case does the 3rd line above evaluates to 'true'? I mean, which device runs iPhone OS and use one of listed CPU's?
- Is there a use case where I should re-define `CA_PREFER_FIXED_POINT` to 0 (when programming for iPhone)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read the contents of the link, and this line in your headers again:

```
#define kAudioUnitSampleFractionBits 24
```

The canonical type for audio **input** and **output** is equivalent to SInt16.

The canonical type for other audio processing, such as the new iOS 5 filter Audio Units, is 8.24 signed fixed-point.

If you do your own DSP code for near real-time iOS audio processing, benchmark it with the different types, as on some of the newest ARM cores, sequences of 32-bit floats are often faster than using either of the above canonical types, and coded in NEON asm code even faster.

Answer (score 3):

In its [Core Audio Essentials](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/CoreAudioEssentials/CoreAudioEssentials.html) Apple clarifies about **Canonical Audio Data Formats**:

> Canonical Audio Data Formats Depending on the platform, Core Audio has
>   one or two “canonical” audio data formats in the sense that these
>   formats may be:
>
> - Required as an intermediate format in conversions
> - The format for which
>     a service in Core Audio is optimized
> - A default, or assumed, format, when you do not otherwise specify an ASBD
>
> The canonical formats in Core Audio are as follows:
>
> - iOS input and output Linear PCM with 16-bit integer samples
> - iOS audio units and other audio processing Noninterleaved linear PCM with 8.24-bit fixed-point samples
> - Mac input and output Linear PCM with 32-bit floating point samples
> - Mac audio units and other audio processing Noninterleaved linear PCM with 32-bit floating point samples

**But:** If you have a look into the `CoreAudioTypes.h` in iOS 8 you will find a discussion on that:

> The "canonical" flags are deprecated. `CA_PREFER_FIXED_POINT` is
>   discouraged because floating-point performance on iOS is such that
>   fixed point is no longer truly preferred. All Apple-supplied
>   `AudioUnits` support floating point. Replacement should be done with
>   careful consideration of the format being specified or expected, but
>   often `kAudioFormatFlagsCanonical` can be replaced with
>   `kAudioFormatFlagsNativeFloatPacked`, and
>   `kAudioFormatFlagsAudioUnitCanonical` with
>   `kAudioFormatFlagsNativeFloatPacked | kAudioFormatFlagIsNonInterleaved`.